# Can I commit files to GitHub from Android Phone

Tags: android, github

I've been doing a school assignment on HTML and CSS.  It was an easy assignment and I almost missed the due date when I was away for the weekend.

I have done the assignment on my phone but to hand it in I have to put it on my GitHub page.

Is there a way to put files from Android onto my GitHub page?

Comment: Why the down vote? Was there something wrong with my question? Being relatively new to Stack Exchange i'd love to know where the question went wrong.

Comment: I have not downvoted you because you were a school student at the time, but I felt like downvoting because you wrote "It was an easy assignment and I almost missed the due date when I was away for the weekend." which is not something any of us needs to know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to put files from Android onto my GitHub page?

Sure.

Choose [a Git client from the Play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=git%20client&c=apps) and install it. There are a few free options and a few paid ones. Some are essentially read-only cients, but others will let you make changes.

Note that with Git you aren't really "putting files onto your GitHub page", but rather creating commits on your local device and pushing those commits to GitHub.

Alternatively, you should be able to use GitHub's [web editor](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository/) to make changes directly from Chrome or Firefox (though you might have to request the desktop web interface instead of the mobile one).

Comment: @user1271772, I've modified my Google Play link to search for "git client", not just "git". That should provide a better list of options. Please don't expect me to pick one for you; we expect you to do [a certain amount of work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/354577) here. I don't think it's unreasonable to ask you to go though a list of results, try a few apps out, and pick one you like. At the moment SGit, MGit, and Forker are the top free results. I've personally used SGit and Pocket Git (paid) with reasonable success.

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit from the mobile version of GitHub website. You have to switch to desktop site and then edit. In mobile version of GitHub site, the editor is not available.

Alternatively, you can replace "blob" with "edit" in the mobile URL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use the command line on your phone, and you are running Android 5 or above, then try installing the Termux app.  You can then `pkg install git`, clone your GitHub repository (if you don't yet have a repository, create one on GitHub's website and it will tell you the commands you need), move the files into it (if you've already edited files outside of Termux, then you might need to type `termux-setup-storage` and check inside the `storage` directory to find them), and do the `git add *` and `git commit -am files` and `git push`.

Alternatively if it is just one or two small files then you might find GitHub's "online code editor" useful.

A third option is if you are able to transfer the files to a server somewhere (for example, use SpeedSoftware Explorer to create a zip, and use a CGI script or something to help you upload that zip to your server, or improvise an `scp` command or equivalent, or even use DropBox if you also have it installed in your home directory on the server), then SSH into the server and run the `git` commands from there.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get file editing + committing work via the GitHub Android app, but it's hack-ish. Hopefully it doesn't stop working in future.

Steps:

- Install GitHub Android.
- From within the app, go to your desired repo's root.
- Share the link with a text editor or message app.
- Touch that link. It'll open the GitHub *desktop* page inside the *Android GitHub app*.
- Touch the options (3 dots) in the right hand corner, select "Add to Home screen"
- Minimize everything.
- Touch your new shortcut (will open in app), and browse to the desired repo.

Voila - full editing and control on phone.

The nice thing about this approach is that the home screen shortcut opens the app as a kind of separate mode, meaning you can still use the normal app functions by opening the "real" app icon in your app drawer. This launches two instances of the app: the traditional read-only version, and the edit-happy version - and you can switch between the two via your recents.

Comment: Grate! This helped me. What about open github.dev bro?